# SQL - Conditional Group By Statement With Sum

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, conditional-statements, having-clause

I have a table with employees and my task is to calculate the overall annual earnings per branch.

The table looks like this:

[image: Original Table]

The special condition is to only sum the total earnings of branches were no voluntary employees are working.

The preferred results would look like this:

[image: Results Table]

Is there a lean possibility in SQL to sum only groups that fulfill such a special condition without using the help of joins and additional select statements?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation, and filter out branches that have at least one voluntary  with a `having` clause:

```
select branch_id, sum(earnings) as earnings
from earnings_table
group by branch_id
having max(case when employee_type = 'Voluntary' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Some databases have neater options to express the `having` clause.

In MySQL or SQLite:

```
having max(employee_type = 'Voluntary') = 0
```

In Postgres;

```
having not bool_or(employee_type = 'Voluntary')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `HAVING` clause as follows:

```
select branch_id, sum(earning) as total_earnings
  from your_Table t
group by branch_id
having count(case when employee_type = 'Voluntary' then 1 end) = 0
```